# Attask Custom Fields Create Error

Tags: attask, workfront-api

How to update the Field name with some special character just like:

Customer #2 First Name
Customer #2 Last Name
Customer #3 First Name
Customer #3 Last Name

My request is given below but it returns error:
I have checked only because of this '#' used in custom fields.

https://mycomapny.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api-unsupported/proj?method=post&apiKey=apiKey&templateID=templateID&companyID=companyID&ownerID=ownerID&name=Testing Project API&DE:Customer First Name=ABC1&DE:Customer Last Name=ABC1&
ABC2&DE:Customer #2 Last Name=ABC2&DE:Customer #3 First Name=XYZ3&DE:Customer #3 Last Name=XYZ3

Please help how to create or update this field value containing #.

Answer (score 0):

You need to urlEncode the special character for # the url encoded is %23 so your call would be

```
https://mycomapny.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api-unsupported/proj?method=post&apiKey=apiKey&templateID=templateID&companyID=companyID&ownerID=ownerID&name=Testing Project API&DE:Customer First Name=ABC1&DE:Customer Last Name=ABC1& ABC2&DE:Customer %232 Last Name=ABC2&DE:Customer %233 First Name=XYZ3&DE:Customer %233 Last Name=XYZ3
```

Comment: No its does not work for me i just doing first create the project with template id. and then using json updates= { etc etc }
with %23 it works... but in url it does not work for me... :(
but thenks for the help brother.. really appreciate it!